# How to call setOnCloseRequest from anywhere to close application if an error occurs in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx-8, handler

How can I close my JavaFX application after showing the error in a dialog?

In main:

```
primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(WindowEvent we) {
        logger.debug("Tool is closing...");
        JDBCUtil.closeConnection(); // necessary
    }
});
```

In another class :

```
// ... creating Dialog, Alert, etc. 
Optional<ButtonType> result = exception.showAndWait();
if (result.get().getButtonData() == ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE) {
    Platform.exit(); // but the handle method isn't called then...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `setOnHiding()` event will be handled, `setOnCloseRequest()` will not be called when application level shutdown has been detected (`Platform.exit()` has been called).

This is not connected to the stage, so even if you add `setOnCloseRequest()` in your `dialog` stage, it wouldn't be called.

Those kind of stage level methods (e.g. `setOnCloseRequest`, `setOnCloseRequest`) are not the correct methods to detect and process application level shutdown event. Instead, you should implement [stop()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html#stop%28%29) from Application, to detect application shutdown, and handle needed actions.

So in your primary application,

```
@Override
public void stop() throws Exception {
     JDBCUtil.closeConnection(); 
     super.stop();
}
```